# Incorrect render method ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, dom, ecmascript-6

I keep getting this error message(see 1st image below), when I run my ReactJS app(in the browser, and in the terminal).

Error message in browser:

[image]

My problem is that I have exported my App.js file. So I don't understand where the error message is coming from. All of my other files in the app have also been exported correctly.

Code from Code Editor:

[image]

Here is my code as text from the App.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
//import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import Navigation from './Components/Navigation';
import SideNavigation from './Components/SideNavigation';
import Backdrop from './Components/Backdrop';
//import DrawerToggleButton from './Components/DrawerToggleButton';
import About from './Components/About';
//import Portfolio from //'./Components/Portfolio';
import Contact from './Components/Contact';
import Footer from './Components/Footer';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {
 render() {
   return(
    <div>
     <Navigation />
     <SideNavigation />
    <Backdrop />
    {/* <DrawerToggleButton /> */}
    <About />
    {/* <Portfolio /> */}
    <Contact />
   <Footer /> 
    </div>

   )
    }
  }

  export default App;
```

Comment: The error message says **Check Your render method**

Comment: Please post the code from your `App.js` here.

Comment: Please include the error and your code as text rather than images: see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question for more information

Comment: I posted my App.js code in my original question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are number of reasons you can face this error.
1) If your App Component looks like this `export const App = () => ....all your code`,
try importing your App component like this `import {App} from './App'`

2) Try making your App component using a class like `export default class App extends React.Component`

Hope this helps..

Comment: Hi! I tried the first option, and got a 'Compiled Successfully' message in the terminal, but in the browser, I am still getting the same error message. The second option you suggested did not work with my code. Thank you!